# PHP loop over passing arguments to a function

Tags: php, loops

I have a function called `array_sum_identical_keys()` which adds (as a sum) array values of identical keys.
I have X number of arrays called `$array1` `$array2` `$array3` etc. all created from a loop earlier in the code.

Since I have X number of arrays, I need to create a loop which will add up all of the array values with my custom function `array_sum_identical_keys()`, given that I don't know how many arrays I have.

I need to pass each array as an argument to `array_sum_identical_keys()` like `array_sum_identical_keys($array1, $array2, ...)` but I need to do this within a loop, adding each argument every time the loop iterates.

**In simpler terms**: I need to add an argument to a function each time a loop iterates, but I need the function to just be called once, with all arguments.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: I have an answer but post how you create arrays if you need more.

Comment: strore each array `$array1`, `$array2` etc in an array itself. then pass that array as parameter to your method

Comment: The reference manual gives some good tips, http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php then scroll down to Variable-length argument lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating separate arrays, create a multi-dimensional array in the loops that is an array of your arrays.  Then just send that to `call_user_func_array()`:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('your_func', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather not deal with variable length argument lists, and would rather create a solution from simple parts, then this sounds like a perfect use for the [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php). If your `array_sum_identical_keys` works for two input arrays, and you have all of your arrays bundled up into a multidimensional array `$arrays`, then you can simply put the following:

```
$arrays_summed = array_reduce($arrays, 'array_sum_identical_keys');
```